# "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod..." but there are no pending signature approvals

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline script, I get the error `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods drop java.util.List int`.

So far, so good.  But when I go to the ScriptApproval page, there are no pending signature approvals.

The odd thing is that on a different Jenkins system, when I ran the same command, it added it to the pending script approvals, and I was able to use it just fine.

Is there a way to either

1. force it to add that function as a pending script approval?
2. manually add it to the list of approved scripts?

Comment: I'd recommend adding it to [the script-security plugin for others in the long run.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists/generic-whitelist). I wasn't able to reproduce this issue on a local instance, so maybe something else is going on? Was it already removed by somebody else or possibly a Jenkins restart?

Comment: I suppose it's possible that it was removed by somebody.  If so, how do I re-add it?

Comment: You can just rerun your build and it should just show up again. I _think_ it will show up in the logs, too. If not, then I think there is a way you can run a script or something to add the signature in a different way.

Comment: No -- the problem is that it *isn't* showing up, no matter how many times I run it.

Comment: Ok, I think you might be running into [JENKINS-34973](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34973).

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the similar problem, Jenkins did not add any static method to script approval page.

Think it was a some kind of bug with Jenkins and security plugin, because I have never met this behavior before. As workaround I had to manual execute the next script in "Script Console" page on `https://JENKINS_URL/script`

```
def scriptApproval = org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval.get()
scriptApproval.approveSignature("staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance")
scriptApproval.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, is your pipeline multibranch?
Mine was and I solved it by doing the following:
Add the method invocation 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods drop' in another pipeline that is NON multibranched, if you dont have any just create a dummy one.
Run the pipeline, it will now appear under the script approval section.
Apparently this bug only affects multibranch pipelines.
Hope it can still be useful.

Comment: Yes, it was multibranch.